# Any others bootstrap table styles?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Are there any other twitter-bootstrap table classes besides class="table table-striped", i'm looking for a table that completely covers the background, the striped only covers the odd rows. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rails has nothing to do with the table classes you are using.  Do you mean Bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, i'm using the twitter bootstrap gem

Comment: What is preventing you to write your own CSS class?

Comment: nothing, i was just wondering if there were already some table templates already done that matched what i needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap, especially version 3, is not intended to be a theme designer. Use some basic CSS to achieve what you're after. Surely you have a custom CSS overrides file going, right?

```
table.my-class {background-color: #eee;}
```